# proof that $f(E\cup F)=f(E)\cup f(F)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I am supposed to show that $f(E\cup F)=f(E)\cup f(F)$.

Proof 
\begin{align*}
f(E\cup F)&=\{f(x):x\in E \cup F\}\\
&=\{f(x):x\in E \text{ or } F\}\\
&=\{f(x):x\in E \text{ or } f(x):x\in F\}\\
&=f(E)\cup f(F)
\end{align*}
I feel there is something wrong with the transition from third step to fourth because in the same way I could prove
\begin{align*}
f(E\cap F)&=\{f(x):x\in E \cap F\}\\
&=\{f(x):x\in E \text{ and } F\}\\
&=\{f(x):x\in E \text{ and } f(x):x\in F\}\\
&=f(E)\cap f(F)
\end{align*}
... isn't it?But the second result is not generally true. 
Can anyone write out a better proof and tell me what is going on here.

Comment: Even the second line is somewhat dubious in my opinion: "$x\in E\text{ or }F$" looks like an ambiguous English-language sentence loosely translated into math symbols. It can't really mean $x\in (E\text{ or }F)$, because "$E\text{ or }F$" is not notation describing a set, and it can't mean $(x\in E)\text{ or }F$, because $F$ does not have a truth value. Mathematically, I don't think it means anything at all. Then we start butchering the "$:$" notation for sets on the third line, again to something with no meaning that I can see; not surprising it leads to a false result in your second example.

Comment: Normally $\cup$ is used in things like $A\cup B$ and $A_1\cup \cdots \cup A_n$ and $\bigcup$ is used in things like $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^N A_n.$  I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: The notation $$ \{f(x):x\in E \text{ or } f(x):x\in F\} $$ is new to me, and it's nonsense. $\qquad$

Comment: I don't mean to be harsh on you. I just think it is helpful, especially at this level, to treat mathematical notation as something with a very rigid syntax that you have to obey exactly (like the way a programming language environment will complain about a "syntax error" and refuse even to compile your code if you write a sequence of symbols not documented in the language definition). It will help to avoid errors, and will also be a clue as to when to stop writing equations and start using words (because you don't know how to write the necessary equation).

Comment: By the way, you showed good initiative in coming up with the "bad example" and asking about it here. +1 for that!

Comment: noted; thanks @DavidK

Comment: hmm.. okay! @MichaelHardy

Comment: @DavidK would this work? $y\in f(E\cup F)$
$\iff \big(\exists x\in E\cup F\big)\big(y=f(x)\big)$
$\iff \big(\exists x\in E$ or $\exists x\in F\big)\big(y=f(x)\big)$
$\iff\big(\exists x_1\in E\big)\big(y=f(x)\big)$ or $\big(\exists x_1\in E\big)\big(y=f(x)\big)$
$\iff y\in f(E)$ or $y\in f(F)$
$\iff y\in f(E\cup F)$

Comment: last part I mean to say $y \in f(E)\cup f(F)$

Comment: I'd say $(\exists x\in E\text{ or }\exists x\in F)$ is still a little too informal, though maybe you could just skip that formula; $(\exists x\in E\cup F)P(x) \iff (\exists x\in E)P(x) \text{ or } (\exists x\in F)P(x)$ is generally true (as long as all the pieces have truth values). Also, you have a stray subscripts on a couple of $x$s. But this seems to have the right idea and the notation otherwise looks OK to me.

Answer (score 2):

Choose $y\in f(E\cup F)$.  Then there's some $x\in E\cup F$ so that $f(x)=y$.  If $x\in E$, then $y=f(x)\in f(E)$.  On the other hand, if $x\in F$, then $y=f(x)\in f(F)$.  So $y$ is in either $f(E)$ or $f(F)$, so $y\in f(E)\cup f(F)$.  This shows that $f(E\cup F)\subset f(E)\cup f(F)$ (since every element of $f(E\cup F)$ is an element of $f(E)\cup f(F)$).  Can you show the reverse inclusion?